# Mobile notifications through browser based app

Tags: java, javascript, html, mobile, notifications

Is there any way that we can have a 'pure' browser based app on mobile (iPhone & Android) to throw notifications on the mobile device?

If not, could there be a workaround which will allow my app to somehow notify the user of an alert when my app (browser) is in the background?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Moderator I did wrong flagging please ignore that.

Comment: @Real you are quite correct that was the wrong flag. I had to mark your flag as invalid, but I did vote to close (this is hardly a real question).

Answer (score 0):

With 'pure' browser app I understand a WebApp, which is not downloaded through the App Store. And in this case, it's not possible.

You'd have to write a native app with a `UIWebView` to reach this with push notifications and local notifications.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can use Google Cloud Messaging service, which provides API both for server apps and client apps.

There are sample apps of how you may implement your server application (based on Google App Engine or standalone - for generic application server) as well as mobile application.

There is similar service from Apple as well:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

Going this way you'll implement server application, which would be available from any browser (desktop, as well as mobile). So there may be a page for sending a message to a mobile client of your application.

Comment: You always have to install an app through the App Store to send Push Notifications, because the user must be allowed to change the settings for your app and deny it if he want.

Answer (score 0):

This may be long outdated answers to a decade-old question.

With ServiceWorker you can issue notifications

```
let notificationId = 0;

function showNotification() {
    if(Notification.permission == 'granted') {
        self.registration.showNotification("Notification Title", {
        title: "Another Title?",
        action: "Do as I say, not as I do.",
        body: 'Hear ye! Hear ye!',
        icon: 'thing-one-and-thing-two.png',
        vibrate: [200, 100, 200, 100, 200, 100, 200],
        tag: 'notification-'+notificationId++,
        renotify: true,
        requireInteraction: false
        });
    }
}

setTimeout(showNotification, 10000);
```

After you have asked the user to enable notifications in:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Notification.requestPermission().then(r => alert(r))">Allow Notifications!</a>
```

So this works if you do it all correctly.

- register the service worker
- use only HTTPS
- have the user enable the notifications.

What is still unclear to me is why I can vibrate but I can't play a sound? Why the vibration doesn't even seem to work on on my android? Why WhatsApp can play a sound anyway (at least if the page web.whatsapp.com is actually open)? Why on my android the notifications do not ever show up in the foreground but only on my lock screen?